# New fancybox 2, now all links give JS error Object #<HTMLHtmlElement> has no method 'show'

Tags: fancybox

I updated fancybox2. Now all links on the website give a javascript error 
Object # has no method 'show'

Even those links do not have anyfancybox attached.

Can someone explian me why or tell me how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the href tag on the link element for example:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/path/to/original/image"><img src="/path/to/thumnail" /></a>
```